# Jenkins / Docker scanning for docker port on multiple IP's

Tags: ubuntu, docker, jenkins, ubuntu-22.04

I've had a message from my host provider explaining that my server has been scanning other IP's belonging to them (the host provider, not my servers).

The data they sent is this (and more for about a 1 minute timespan):

```
&gt; TIME (UTC)           SRC       SRC-PORT -&gt; DST          DST-PORT SIZE PROT
&gt; 2024-02-16 19:12:44  MY IP 50760 -&gt;     78.46.11.75  2375   60 TCP
&gt; 2024-02-16 19:12:55  MY IP 50760 -&gt;    78.46.11.102  2375   60 TCP
```

I'm trying to track down what has happened. I don't think it's a coincidence that I've just installed docker and jenkins on my server. Docker uses port 2375 by default for external access and my jenkins instance uses port 50000 for agent stuff. The port the scan is coming from is 50760 so is close but not the same as the Jenkins stuff.

Could this be related to Jenkins / Docker in any way? Basically, I just need to explain what happened to the hosting company...

Comment: Jenkins had a major vulnerability recently.

Comment: @AlexD Do you have any information on this? Perhaps a link explaining what it was, versions etc?

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisories/

Answer (score -1):

it's possible that the scanning activity could be related to Docker, especially considering that Docker by default uses port 2375 for external access, and you've recently installed Docker on your server.

Port 50760, from which the scanning activity is originating, is close to the ports used by Docker and Jenkins, but not identical. However, it's worth noting that Docker and Jenkins can sometimes dynamically allocate ports for various processes or communication, so it's possible that the scanning activity could be related to Docker or Jenkins.